# Function writing to the same dictionary or just not writing in it at all

Tags: python, dictionary, huffman-code

I am working on an Huffman project and I have an issue with one specific function. Basically where you create the dictionary from the tree to get the new dict with letters as keys and Huffman code as value (0 and 1).

Btw the whole program is actually way longer obviously but to make it easy for you I just put the non working function as the rest is working as intended.

And the « error » is that when I call my function multiple times it will just write to the same dictionary and replace some keys if they are the same. I tried putting codes = {} in the function itself or as args but then it would return an empty dictionary.

Here is the code :

```
codes = {}
def parcours(arbre, chemin=""):
    
    if arbre.gauche is None:
        codes[arbre.valeur] = chemin
    else:
        parcours(arbre.gauche, chemin+"0")
        parcours(arbre.droit, chemin+"1")
    return codes
        
    
    
print(parcours(creer_arbre(creer_liste(dict_exemple))))
print(parcours(arbre_huffman("testpy.txt")))
```

Here is what it returns :

```
{'b': '00', 'a': '01', 'd': '100', 'e': '1010', 'f': '1011', 'c': '11'}
{'b': '00', 'a': '01', 'd': '100', 'e': '101', 'f': '1011', 'c': '11', ' ': '000', 'p': '001', 'r': '010', 'o': '011', 'j': '100', 't': '110', 'T': '1110', 's': '1111'}
```

Letters are just from an example dictionary but the result clearly shows that the beginning of second run is the same as first run.

Sorry if it’s in French but it should be easy to understand, chemin is « path ». Parcours is like to navigate the tree, arbre is tree, valeur is value.

Comment: The function is just adding values to `codes`, which is declared outside the function and never cleared or re-initialized, so of course those old values will stay there between calls to the function.  If you want to have a different dictionary each time, just move `codes = {}` inside the function.

Comment: Well I said in the post that I tried putting it in the function itself, but them the function will just not write to it at all, I tried with prints to see what it does and it shows a lot of {} (empty dicts).

Comment: Ah, I think I see what your issue is.  (It's very hard to figure out without having your `creer_arbre` and `creer_liste` functions!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define `codes` outside the function, every function call is adding its data to the same dict.

You need to define `codes` inside the function, and make sure to update it with the result of the recursive calls.

```
def parcours(arbre, chemin=""):
    codes = {}
    if arbre.gauche is None:
        codes[arbre.valeur] = chemin
    else:
        codes.update(parcours(arbre.gauche, chemin+"0"))
        codes.update(parcours(arbre.droit, chemin+"1"))
    return codes
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but may I ask you why adding the update actually fixes my issue and what was I doing wring ?

Comment: You defined `codes` outside the function, so every function call was adding its data to the same dict (i.e. the single `codes` dict you defined outside the function).  If you define it inside the function, a new one is created for each call, so they don't all write to the same place.  Not sure how else to explain it unless you can ask a more specific question about it.  :)